# In Postgres, is there a way to have a derived column automatically update when I change the original data that calculated it?

Tags: postgresql

Say I have two tables A and B.
A has two columns:

```
x | y
__|__
1 | 2
3 | 4
5 | 6
```

and B has one column, which is the product of the columns in A:

```
z
_
2
12
30
```

So, say if I changed the value 4 from table A to 3, then the 12 in table B should change to 9 (3*3), but it doesn't. How do I make B automatically update when the original values are changed?

Comment: You shouldn't do that in the first place. You should only keep atomic data in the database or table.
If you really need it, I would create a trigger that updates the necessary data based on the change in value.

Comment: In my case, I do need it. My actual setup is a bit different to what I have described, with one table holding a start date, one holding an end date, and a third holding a cost. Ideally, I'd put the result ((end - start) * cost) into the same table as the end date, but I can't figure out how to do that with a column which derives from different tables, so a new result table is what I've got
How does a trigger work?

Comment: Triggers can be written for the following purposes −

Generating some derived column values automatically;
Enforcing referential integrity;
Event logging and storing information on table access;
Auditing;
Synchronous replication of tables;
Imposing security authorizations;
Preventing invalid transactions.

I think it is exactly what you need.

Comment: B should be a view that selects from A.  While what you want to do is likely also possible with triggers, it's not trivial to create the triggers.  Also, if the rows in A and B don't actually relate to each other, such as with a foreign key, a trigger wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sort of thing that lends itself to a [View](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html):

```
CREATE VIEW 
    results 
AS  
   SELECT a.x * a.y AS product
```

Then you would select from the view for you results. The down side is that this query is run every time you select from the view. There is also the option of a [Materialized View](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html) where you determine when the values are updated with `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW`.

Comment: Even though you can handle this with triggers, I think your answer should be accept as the right answer.